# Trouble creating a new container in Docker. Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name is already in use by container

Tags: macos, docker

I'm running the intro tutorial for Docker on Mac and am getting an error as follows:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 --name docker-tutorial docker101tutorial
```

> docker: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/docker-tutorial" is already in use by container "c5a91ef51a529a00dcbef180560dc2b392f3d9ab05b8c29fa1bf640d64271de7". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name. See 'docker run --help'.

Can you advise on this error — it seems that I would need to delete a prior container? But I don't believe I created one.

Can anyone please advise as to how to troubleshoot this issue as I am not very proficient in terminal and am new to Docker.

When I type `docker ps -a`, I get:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                        PORTS               NAMES
f5ed32612a0a        ubuntu              "bash"                   27 minutes ago      Exited (129) 22 minutes ago                       happy_tesla
b179c651b8d7        hello-world         "/hello"                 40 minutes ago      Exited (0) 40 minutes ago                         mystifying_rubin
c5a91ef51a52        docker101tutorial   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   42 minutes ago      Created                                           docker-tutorial
916e57976203        hello-world         "/hello"                 48 minutes ago      Exited (0) 48 minutes ago                         exciting_dewdney
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make it short, the reason why this is happening to you is because, when you name containers (with the flag `--name foo`), then you have to make sure this name is unique among all the containers you have on your host.

Then regarding your statement:

> Can you advise on this error - it seems that I would need to delete a prior container? But I don't believe I created one

If I read your `docker ps -a` output, this is untrue, you created one 42 minutes ago, see the really last bit of the below line? This is the name of an existing container, `docker-tutorial`:

```
c5a91ef51a52        docker101tutorial   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   42 minutes ago      Created                                           docker-tutorial
```

Just run:

```
docker rm docker-tutorial
```

Then you should be able to go back your tutorial.

---

For the sake of completeness, since it can be unexpected at first usage, the command `docker rm` will output back the name of the container that it just deleted:

```
$ docker rm I-do-exist                  
I-do-exist
```

And if you do not have such a named container, then it will output a clear error:

```
$ docker rm I-do-not-exist
Error: No such container: I-do-not-exist
```

Comment: If I run docker rm docker-tutorial, the next output is "docker-tutorial" and then when I run the intiial command it says: 

373bb03c26f2fcd7249dcb37dbb0a67c1b92a2a3014e227ca275b82b4a4db377
docker: Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80: bind: address already in use.

Comment: When I type docker ps-a after removing the tutorial container, it does not show there anymore so I believe it is removed successfully (although now I am getting this port related issue)

Comment: That means there is something else occupaying the port 80 on your mac

Comment: Are you running apache locally on your mac, maybe?

Comment: I am not running apache. Is there a way to see what is on my port 80? I dont believe I have anything else running (at least not intentionally)

Comment: Better yet, if you don't know, bind your container to the http child port: `8080` by doing `docker run -d -p 8080:80 --name docker-tutorial docker101tutorial`, then in the rest of the tutorial, when they instruct you to access `localhost` in your browser, rather access `localhost:8080`

Comment: and to identify what runs on port 80, do a `sudo lsof -i :80`

Comment: It looks like the binding the container in the child port worked - can you explain in lay terms what that did?

Comment: What does the following mean is running on the port 8080:80? When I type sudo lsof -i :80 it shows this:

COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
httpd     101 root    4u  IPv6 0x5d875d188a6a8b4b      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     295 _www    4u  IPv6 0x5d875d188a6a8b4b      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   22607 _www    4u  IPv6 0x5d875d188a6a8b4b      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   22673 _www    4u  IPv6 0x5d875d188a6a8b4b      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)

Comment: `-p host-port:container-port` "connects" the port `host-port` of you host to the `container-port` of the container. Of course, if there is something already running on the host on that port, that fails with the message you got _address already in use_

Comment: So yes, you do have httpd, so apache running. If you don't care about it, just stop it, then you can follow the docker tutorial as is: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-macosx-starting-stopping-apache-web-server/

Comment: Why would apache server be running? Is that a default when you run MacOS? I don't recall starting it for any purposes?

Comment: Apache is installed per default, and you can serve a site from the /Sites folder of a user. It is not mandatory, though, and from what I know, on the last version os MacOS this is not started anymore

Comment: In Docker version 20.10.2, you can't use the name for rm command.  You must use the 12 character value in the first column as the identifier.

Answer (score 1):

The command being `docker run` and not `run`, I suspect there might be some typo, maybe a non-printable character.

Try to type the complete command from a fresh prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Please post the command you are running again removing the backslash

Please post output `docker ps -a` it will show you what containers are there running/stopped

Comment: Thanks - I forgot to remove the backslash from the edited question. I have added the requested code to the question

Comment: there you have it in the output shows the image name being used. created. you will have to delete "docker container rm <id>"

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your problem with just two commands

In your terminal type:

1. `docker ps -qa`

to find the name that you called your docker container  and check the its status says 'exited'(i.e. Container called 'Zen-wu')

2. Select your docker container number and remove it like the example below

`docker rm 828a52b426f2`

optional

If you want to remove **All** the exited docker containers do the following command

`docker rm $(docker ps -qa)`